# How to exclude ClientAbortException from SimpleMappingExceptionResolver

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, exception

I am using a SimpleMappingExceptionResolver that sends all exceptions to an view where it is nicely rendered. That works except one case:
If the user requests a page, and then send and "Abort" (*I don't know exactly how that works, but I noticed that if I click an HTTP post form submit button very fast and often the Firefox 7 somehow notify the server that it is not longer interested in the result.*) Then the Tomcat 6 rises an [`ClientAbortException`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/catalina/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/ClientAbortException.html) when one try to render the page, or write the the http response in any kind.

Now starts the trouble: the `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` "catches" the exception and trys to render it *nicely* to an html page. This then causes in a Stream already closed exception which pollute the log file. (`java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response`)

What I have done so fare, is to register the an empty jsp page for the "ClientAbortException". But I feel that this is a Hack. On the other Hand I guess this is not a so uncommen problem, because I will expect it in nearly every spring application that renders all exception. So does anybody have experience with that problem, or has an idea of an not so hacky solution?

```
<bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver"
  p:defaultErrorView="uncaughtException">
    <property name="exceptionMappings">
        <props>
           <prop key=".MissingServletRequestParameterException">
               resourceNotFound
           </prop>
           <prop key=".ClientAbortException">nothing</prop>
        </props>
     </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extend `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver`, override `doResolveException()` method, and in case the exception name is `ClientAbortException` and `response.isCommitted()` return `null` instead of returning `super.doResolveException()`.

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions of Spring, you can also use the [@ExceptionHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ExceptionHandler.html) annotation, possibly with [@ControllerAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) (for global handling).

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalDefaultExceptionHandler {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @ExceptionHandler(ClientAbortException.class)
    public void clientAbortExceptionHandler(HttpServletRequest request, ClientAbortException e) {
        // This usually means the browser closed or disconnected or
        // something. We can't do anything. To avoid excessive stack traces
        // in log, just print a simple message and return null
        String username = "<NONE>";
        Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
        if (principal != null) {
            username = principal.getName();
        }
        logger.warn("ClientAbortException: username={},remoteAddr={},userAgent={},requestedURL={}", username,
                request.getRemoteAddr(), request.getHeader("User-Agent"), request.getRequestURL());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, registering the `nothing` view for the `Exception` you don't want to handle is elegant way; as opposed to feeling of hack; as you can have even more than one exception you don't / won't want to render as compared to other exceptions.

I won't recommend coming up with a custom implementation for HandlerExceptionResolver; as it may increase maintainability costs.